At least 3n/2-2 comparisons needed to find minimum and maximum of an unsorted array

Show that $\left\lfloor \frac{3n}2\right\rfloor-2$ comparisons are necessary to find the minimum and maximum in an unsorted array of $n$ elements

So we keep a tag $M$ for the possible maximum and a tag $m$ for the possible minimum on each element. So initially before the algorithm starts any element can be minimum or maximum. So all the elements have both tags. At the end of the algorithm, only one minimum and one maximum are there and other elements have no possibility of becoming minimum and maximum. So at the end of the algorithm, there can be one $M$ tag on the maximum and one $m$ tag on the minimum element. So the algorithm removes $2n-2$ tags in total.
Now the algorithm wants to remove the tags with as less comparisons as possible. Now if any element has both $M$ and $m$ tags then it is not compared before. If two elements which never been compared are compared then whatever the advisory says the larger one will have the $m$ tag removed and the smaller one will have the $M$ tag removed. So in this case $2$ tags were removed. But at most $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor$ such comparisons possible. For other comparisons assume at least one tag is not there in one of the elements

If $(m,M)$ tag compared with $M$ tag. The advisory can make the only $M$ tag element larger so that the $M$ tag from $(m, M)$ tagged element is removed only. Similarly, if $(m, M)$ tag is compared with $m$ tag, then advisory makes the only $m$ tag element smaller, and for the same reason only one element is removed.
If $M$ tag is compared with $M$ tag then smaller one has $M$ tag removed.
If $m$ tag is compared with $m$ tag then larger one has $m$ tag removed.

Only when a $M$ tag is compared with the $m$ tag is if the $m$ tagged element becomes larger than the $M$ tag then both the tag is removed but I don't want that. I want to ensure only one tag will be removed. How can I claim that?

Comparing $m$ with $M$ makes no sense, $m$ means "could be minimal, isn't possibly maximal" (lost at least a comparison) and $M$ "could be maximal, definitely not minimal" (won at least one).

If you've quoted the question correctly, it is asking you to show that this many comparisons are NECESSARY. It is not asking you to show that they are SUFFICIENT.

advisory the adversary

Comparing two elements having $m$ tag and $M$ tag can't remove exactly one tag. Either the first element is greater than the second one, and both tags should be removed, or the first element is less than the second one, so no tag should be removed. Since the second option is possible such comparison has no chance to decrease minimum number of comparisons.
Edit. So my statement is: for a deterministic algorithm which allows such comparison there exists an input sequence such that the comparison will be useless (i. e., will change no tags). Suppose the algorithm compares elements $x_i$ and $x_j$ with tags $m$ and $M$ correspondingly and $x_i > x_j$. Before the comparison there are some elements (at least one) that are less than $x_j$ and some elements (at least one) that are greater than $x_i$. At this point no element is known to be greater than $x_j$, as well as no element is known to be less than $x_i$.
Then we as adversary can swap values $x_i$ and $x_j$ in the input sequence. Value of $x_i$ decreases, value of $x_j$ increases. All elements that were greater than $x_i$ are still greater than $x_i$. All elements that were less than $x_j$ are still less than $x_j$. It means that before comparison between $x_i$ and $x_j$ all comparisons have the same result. But the comparison between $x_i$ and $x_j$ now changes no tags.
This is the way how for any deterministic algorithm which allows comparison between elements with different single tags we can increase the number of comparisons which give the same state of tags. (For multiple such comparisons we do the same multiple times.) That's how we show that such comparison is useless.
A randomized algorithm with non-deterministic order of comparisons may be considered as a deterministic algorithm with additional input of values of all inner random variables. Thus it gets the same conclusions about minimum possible number of comparisons, just with some positive probability.

Why as an adversary i can always make the second option possible for such comparison.

@SassyMath I've added some details
